# Sync data between couchdb and a Lotus Notes Database

Tags: couchdb, lotus-notes, hoodie

I have to migrate a Lotus Application to couchdb/hood.ie.

anyone seen a kind of sync between Lotus Notes/Domino and couchdb?

thx

Pitt

Answer (score 2):

Aside from writing a custom data exporter and re-building the app in web technology, I think you are out of luck. Hoodie/CouchDB are good choices for getting an app out of the Notes land, though :)

Answer (score 0):

> a kind of sync

install a RSS feed application into the Lotus Notes DB and start polling (and yes, that could only be a workaround to finally leave the Notes System)